# How to display two html files without iframes (locally scoped css) using React JS

Tags: reactjs

So i'm trying to display two (or more) html files on the same page without using iframes (for various reasons, doing so would require a rewrite of my app).

So far, i've been able to parse through the HTML files and display them side-by-side on the screen (inside of a DIV container)

And now i'm trying to get each HTML file styled using css.

My problem is that each HTML file uses a different stylesheet...

1. i need to be able to apply the css to each HTML file so as not to cross over and influence the other HTML file displayed on the page.
2. i need to be able to bring in each stylesheet and apply them even though they are 3rd party urls provided by the user (in other words, i don't have the option of downloading and including them locally before the app is compiled).

I found this library: https://github.com/yiminghe/react-scoped-style

...and that solves #1 (in that i can have styles that i write locally, scoped to the DIV container that surrounds each HTML file displayed on my screen), but i'm not sure how to use 3rd party css urls using that (or any) library.

Any thoughts/advice?

To be clear, the 3rd party css file will not be known at compile time. The user is that one that will decide while they use my app what 3rd party css urls they want to apply to their web page.

What do you think?

Comment: what's that thing craigslist use to use... It was a tag...

Comment: @quantumworks, not sure what you mean?